# Update a specific element in an array of objects in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add new fields in this array, and just update them when already existing but I can't manage to get it to work. I've been trying many things but the latest method I tried is this one below, that well... it doesn't work. Could anyone help me, please?

```
       if (req.method === 'PATCH') {
    const { title, description, socials } = req.body;
    const { name, link } = socials;

    try {
    
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                email: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
            },
            {
                title,
                description,
                $set: {
                    socials: { name, link },
                },
            }
        );
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            title,
            description,
            socials,
        });
        user.save();
```

Comment: Maybe `$set: { socials: {name: 'Facebook', link: 'http://facebook.com'} }`?

Comment: Can you explain more on how the array looks? And are you updating by the filters email, title and description?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think it works, but now I am having another issue. I get an array of objects from the front-end and need to check whether each object already exists, and if it does, update it. Otherwise, create it, and still can't manage

Comment: @fractal397 I realized I was filtering wrong and I corrected it. Gonna update the main post now, the array I am getting from the front end looks like


`[
  { name: 'Facebooasdask', link: 'http://12312312' },
  { name: 'github', link: 'http://12asdasda2' },
  { name: 'linkedin', link: 'http://aaaaa' }
]`

Comment: so I think at this point I just need to figure out how to loop through the array I get with $set and it should be fine